# Crystal Report display three records per page

Tags: crystal-reports, report

This is the record in 1st employee in page and there is another employee results in other page. In every page there is only 1 employee details:

[image]

All I want is in every page, 3 employee details will be displayed not only one.

This is the the image also in my Crystal Report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you go through the Sections in the Section Expert, is the "New Page After" or "New Page Before" chekbox checked anywhere? Uncheck it. Try the first and the last visible section, it should be there.

That will give you as many employee details in one page as possible.